# "Calling Thread must be STA" error although the thread is STA

Tags: wpf, exception, invoke, dispatcher

I'm having a little trouble with my STA thread in WPF.

I do the following:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(CreateAndShow), null);
```

with CreateAndShow looking like this:

```
_mainWindow = new PresentWindow();
// not really important what happens in the next lines, the error is before this
AddPerspectives(); 
MainWindow = _mainWindow;
MainWindow.Show();
```

Now, I get an Exception, in the line where the PresentWindow constructor starts, stating that the calling thread needs to be an STA thread.

I put in a break point just before creating the PresentWindow. The AppartmentState of the current thread is STA. If I call CreateAndShow from a different point (without the invoke, but directly in the exact same STA thread), it works perfectly fine.

I'm sure there's a very simple explanation to all this, but I can't find it. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating a thread in the constructor?

Comment: No, the constructor is just calling InitializeComponent() that was created by VS, and creating some lists and event handlers.

Comment: But the exception isn't raised somewhere in the constructor, but at the very start of it. It in the line

Comment: public PresentWindow() - by the way, how to you make a line break in this comment text box?

Comment: Try shift+enter. 
Are you creating the window in a new Thread?

It doesn't make sense that new PresenWindow() throws an exception if all you do is call InitializeComponent.
Care to paste the full or more code?

Comment: Crap! I just realized that after calling BeginInvoke, I call the CreateAndShow() method, which of course will be executed by the non-STA thread.

Thanks for the quick help anyways!